# Multiple metrics, multiple users, multiple events, R

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be simple and probably would be if I was willing to slot it into a really ugly dataframe, but I want to try and clean this up. I need to evaluate let's say 10 people. On 4 different metrics across let's say 12 different events. I will have a PDF to work from.  This is not a homework assignment. I simply haven't done anything useful with R in 3 years.
So to break this down how I want to be able to use it.

```
User: 1
Event: 1
Metric1: val1
Metric2: val2
Metric3: val3
Metric4: val4

User: 1
Event: 2
M1-4: some val

User 1:
Event: etc
```

I would like to be able to evaluate each user for their performance per event.
Evaluate their performance per metric
Evaluate their performance on their best scores over the entire set of events.

Essentially I'm not sure how to organize this. I'm looking to keep it flat, ideally without making it ugly, but I guess I could build a relational database. I completely forget and haven't been able to figure out how to make a usable "object" in R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: What aspect of your schema would make a dataframe ugly? It looks pretty rectangular to me, should fit nicely?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do data entry like this is using [tribble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html) from the tibble package. That allows you to build the table row-by-row. For example: `tibble::tribble(~ user, ~ event, ~ metric, ~ value, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1.4, 1, 2, 1, 9)`